# AndroidMaifest куда добавляется код

Tags: android, unity3d

У меня есть AndroidMAnifest (Unity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN-->
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

куда нужно добавлять такие строки никак не пойму

```
tools:replace = "android:fullBackupContent"
               android:allowBackup = "true"
               android:fullBackupContent = "true"
```

будет хорошо если помимо ответа еще будет ссылка на изучение этой темы

Comment: Сюда https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element

Comment: спасибо, не туда вообще пытался все это дело засунуть